# How to remove all characters from string apart from emoji

Tags: javascript, regex

This function currently removes all emoji characters from a string using regex. How can I reverse this so it removes all characters apart from the emoji characters?

```js
var ranges = [
  '\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]', // U+1F300 to U+1F3FF
  '\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f]', // U+1F400 to U+1F64F
  '\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff]'  // U+1F680 to U+1F6FF
];

function removeEmoji() {
  var str = $('#emoji').html();
 
  str = str.replace(new RegExp(ranges.join('|'), 'g'), '');
  $("#emoji").html(str);
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  removeEmoji();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="emoji">
  <li></li>
  <li>or Smiling Face</li>
  <li>or  Smiling Face</li>
  <li>or Smiling Face</li>
  <li></li>
  <li>or Smiling Face</li>
  <li>or  Smiling Face</li>
  <li>or Smiling Face</li>
</ul>

<button>Push Me</button>
```

Comment: Try `str = str.replace(new RegExp("(" + ranges.join('|') + ")|.", 'g'), '$1');`. Or, to preserve tags, `str = str.replace(new RegExp("(<[^<]*?>|" + ranges.join('|') + ")|.", 'g'), '$1');`

Comment: That's a good answer, @WiktorStribiżew - you should post it as one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `str.replace()` with `str.match()`!

Note that I have copied this snippet from your answer, and it is getting and replacing the entire html of the `<ul>`. This includes the `<li>` elements.

```js
var ranges = [
  '\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]', // U+1F300 to U+1F3FF
  '\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f]', // U+1F400 to U+1F64F
  '\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff]'  // U+1F680 to U+1F6FF
];

function removeEmoji() {
  var str = $('#emoji').html();
 
  str = str.match(new RegExp(ranges.join('|'), 'g'), '');
  $("#emoji").html(str);
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  removeEmoji();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="emoji">
  <li></li>
  <li>or Smiling Face</li>
  <li>or  Smiling Face</li>
  <li>or Smiling Face</li>
  <li></li>
  <li>or Smiling Face</li>
  <li>or  Smiling Face</li>
  <li>or Smiling Face</li>
</ul>

<button>Push Me</button>
```